# How do I sort a dictionary while retaining its keys?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I know it's possible to sort a dict for its values using this:

```
>>> mydict = {'silver': 300, 'gold': 500, 'bronze': 100, 'platinum': 1000}
>>> items = mydict.items()
>>> print sorted([value for key, value in items])
[100, 300, 500, 1000]
```

But what if I want to sort the values *inside* the dict so I still have the keys? The output should look like this:

```
{'platinum': 1000, 'gold': 500, 'silver': 300, 'bronze': 100}
```

Is there any method to achieve this?

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered. We can print things like that, but it won't be a dictionary.

Comment: You can't impose a particular order a dictionary because it is actually a hashtable - the key-item pairs will come out in the order determined by the hashing function.

Comment: @MatteoItalia It's even worse. The order depends on the hash values of all other keys, the size of the dict, the history of insertions and deletions, and in recent versions on the output of a PRNG.

Comment: Here you are [link](http://obroll.com/how-to-sort-dictionary-by-keys-or-by-values-in-python/)

Comment: `dict(sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))`

Answer (score 6):

You cannot get a dictionary as result as those are inherently unordered. You can get a list of (key, value) pairs though, and fairly easily at that if you use the `key` parameter. For example:

```
sorted(mydict, key=mydict.get)
```

For descending order, either reverse the resulting list or pass `reverse=True` as another argument to `sorted`.

Note that you can use the result of that to construct an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects).

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary is an orderless data structure, so it can't be sorted. But you can convert it to a list of tuples and sort that on the second item of the tuple:

```
>>> mydict = {'silver': 300, 'gold': 500, 'bronze': 100, 'platinum': 1000}
>>> sorted(mydict.items(), key = lambda (metal, price): -price)
[('platinum', 1000), ('gold', 500), ('silver', 300), ('bronze', 100)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> mydict = {'silver': 300, 'gold': 500, 'bronze': 100, 'platinum': 1000}
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> od = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items(),  key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
>>> od
OrderedDict([('platinum', 1000), ('gold', 500), ('silver', 300), ('bronze', 100)])
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is *print*, then you still have the keys; just print those too:

```
from operator import itemgetter 

print '{' + ', '.join([': '.join(map(repr, item)) for item in sorted(items, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]) + '}'
```

Output:

```
>>> print '{' + ', '.join([': '.join(map(repr, item)) for item in sorted(mydict.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)]) + '}'
{'platinum': 1000, 'gold': 500, 'silver': 300, 'bronze': 100}
```

Comment: Ouch. While that gives the output OP describes, I doubt that's really what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this,

```
    mydict = {'silver': 300, 'gold': 500, 'bronze': 100, 'platinum': 1000}
    from operator import itemgetter
    sorted(mydict.items(), key=itemgetter(1),  reverse=True)
    o/p = > [('platinum', 1000), ('gold', 500), ('silver', 300), ('bronze', 100)]
```